# How to join lines for multiple blocks (using regex) and keeping each block in its place using notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have these blocks **with not the same amount of lines:**

```
Lorem ipsum sit amet
commodo sollicitudin
lectus fringilla sus
nisl id purus dapibus

Lorem ipsum sit amet
commodo sollicitudin

Lorem ipsum sit amet
commodo sollicitudin
lectus fringilla sus
nisl id purus dapibus
Lorem ipsum sit amet

Lorem ipsum sit amet
commodo sollicitudin
lectus fringilla sus
```

And I want to turn in into these:

```
Lorem ipsum sit amet commodo sollicitudin lectus fringilla sus nisl id purus dapibus

Lorem ipsum sit amet commodo sollicitudin

Lorem ipsum sit amet commodo sollicitudin lectus fringilla sus nisl id purus dapibus Lorem ipsum sit amet

Lorem ipsum sit amet commodo sollicitudin lectus fringilla sus
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

- Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(.)\R(.)`
- Replace with: `$1 $2`
- Check Wrap around
- Search Mode: Regular expression
- Click Replace All

[image: Find and Replace - Results]